# Are there any uses for SELECT command other than retrieving data?

Tags: javascript, sql, database, naming

This question is about naming things.

I'm making a remote database manipulation utility in js. It has a function for retrieving data from the db like this:

```
func_name(table, columns, where) {
    ...
    return [{row as obj}, {row as obj}]
}
```

and I'm tempted to name it "select".

It occurred to me though that this might not be the correct use of terminology since in sql, SELECT doesn't actually retrieve the data but rather provides a handle for retrieval.

Are there any other things you can do with SELECT in sql? Or has it become synonymous enough with data retrieval that this would be ok? What else would you name this operation?

Comment: Another use is to call database functions `select someFunction()` or `select x.* from someFunction() x` but in the bottom line, No there isn't, it all resumes in retrieving data. About your function name I would not recommend to use a name that conflicts with reserved words so, `getData` may be a good suggestion.

Comment: What about naming it `query`? Some libraries use this as a method name for querying the database. But also `select` is used in many other libraries.. NB: there is no conflict with SQL reserved words, because you are in another programming environment there (JS).

Comment: I know that it doesn't have any conflict is is just a matter of convention. Of course he can use select that is why I just recommended :)